# Is there a way to speed up recovery from a crash

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I'm trying to find a way to switch Calabash to next Scenario after noticing a crash

```
Retrying.. HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError: (execution expired)
Retrying.. HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError: (execution expired)
Failing... HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError
```

Otherwise it can take up to half an hour before Calabash reestablish connection to Simulator and starts the next Scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> half an hour before Calabash reestablish connection to Simulator

This is very unusual and typically indicates a problem with UIAutomation.

Have you seen the [Hot Topics page](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics)?  In particular:

*NSLog output can cause apps to become unresponsive during testing.*

My best guess is that instruments is hanging for some reason.  Below, I provide details about various variables and their defaults that influence launching and connecting the Calabash server.

I don't think that adjusting any of the variables below will make an difference in your case.

**Reporting Problems**

In the future, please include the details found [in the Report Problems section](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems) of the Calabash iOS Wiki Home Page.

**Environment Variables**

You can find documentation about all the Calabash iOS environment variables [here](http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/file.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.html).

There are several variables you can use to control how long Calabash will wait for a response.

In Calabash iOS, two things need to happen before tests can begin:

1. The instruments command-line tool must launch the app and respond that it has launched the app.
2. Calabash must establish a connection with the embedded server.

You can control how long run-loop waits for instruments to launch the app and report back using the `UIA_TIMEOUT` environment variable.  The default is 10 seconds.  Calabash tells run-loop to try 3 times, for a total of 30 seconds.  Unfortunately, there are no public API docs for run-loop.

The there are two environment variables that control how long Calabash will try to establish a connection with the embedded server:

- `CONNECT_TIMEOUT`
- `MAX_CONNECT_RETRY`

The default is try to reconnect once every 3 seconds 10 times for a total of 30 seconds.

These two variables are also used every time a query or gesture is made - how long does Calabash wait for the server to reply.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this info and play around with settings, test a bit more to identify route cause.